# Does Google Drive Realtime Api use Secure Communication

Tags: https, ws-security, google-drive-realtime-api

Does Google Drive Realtime Api use Secure Communication such as wss or https. If so how is it accomplished? Currently they provide one secret id alone. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is fully based on Google Docs API 3.0, in which `HTTPs/SSL` is automatically employed on all the communications between the client app and online service. So, all your data communications are `SSL` encrypted and there is no need to worry about data interception.

Google API has been used by thousands of thrid party products and is proven to be safe and stable. Google Drive strictly adheres to all instructions and suggestions on Google Docs API document to ensure the highest possible security.

**For more information, check this:**https://support.google.com/work/answer/6056693?hl=en